# Recursion with a foreach loop

Tags: php, recursion

I am trying to build a recursive function but in some way function doesnt display all the directories.What am I missing? I know that i could use for or while, but i want foreach loop. Here is the code:

```
$GLOBALS['testmodus']=0;
$o=new BrowseFolder();
$o->browse('../images/',1);
ta($o);
function ta($ausgabe) {
  echo('<p class="ta">'.__LINE__.$ausgabe.'</p>');
 }


class BrowseFolder{
    private $srcFolder;
    private $ifRecursiv=0;
    private $excludeFileTypes=array('.','..');
    private $filesFound;
    private $deleteFolderPath=0;
    private $makeFolderPath;

    public function browse($srcFolder,$ifRecursiv=0){
        ta($this->filesFound);
        $this->srcFolder=$srcFolder;
        $this->ifRecursiv=$ifRecursiv;
        $this->filesFound=scandir($this->srcFolder);
        $this->filesFound=$this->excludeArrayFromArray($this->filesFound,$this->excludeFileTypes);
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($this->filesFound as $val){
                if(is_file($this->srcFolder.$val)){
                    echo "<li>";
                    echo "$val";
                    echo "</li>";
                    }elseif(is_dir($this->srcFolder.$val) && $this->ifRecursiv==1){
                        ta($this->srcFolder.$val);
                        echo "$val";
                        $this->browse($this->srcFolder.$val.'/',$this->ifRecursiv);

                      }
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }

    private function excludeArrayFromArray($baseArray,$arrayToExclude){  //Exclude an array from another array,and arrange
        $newArray=array_values(array_diff($baseArray,$arrayToExclude));  
        return $newArray;

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add abit more about in what way it does not go through all folders. Also have you considered using DirectoryIterator? http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php

Comment: @Ronni Skansing - probably want the recursive version: http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

Comment: Thanks, @Ronni Skansing.For learning purpose i prefer to use my code,and not the DirectoryIterator. I have two folders with some images. The first is showing up(with other subfolders), the last one is 'eliminated'

Comment: With only two it's hard to see which issue is actually occurring: skipping the last or only taking the first. Add a third dummy folder with some fake files and see what the result is.

Comment: Your function will produce invalid HTML, because when it goes into a sub-directory it outputs another `ul` – that will not be encapsulated within an `li`, so it will end up as a direct child of the parent `ul` … but as we all (should) know, `ul` can have only `li` as child elements.

Comment: Thanks, @ChicagoRedSox. I've tried adding folders.No chance. Only the first one is showing.Then no more...

Comment: @CBroe , I know, thanks.But the main problem is not this.

Comment: Well the code as shown does throw a fatal error for trying to convert an object into a string … so if that’s exactly your code and you did not see such an error, then check your error displaying options first and set them to values that are sensible for developing.

Comment: @ CBroe. Thanks. I know, ta() function is only for testing purpose. Should use print_r in that function ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that if you looked at the web server log, you'd see this error:

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class BrowseFolder could not be converted to string in <filename> on line <XX>
```

Your `BrowseFolder` class has no `__toString()` method, so an attempt to call it in string context is throwing a fatal error (this line: `ta($o);`)

However, that's only problem 1.
Problem 2 is this:

```
$this->srcFolder=$srcFolder;
```

Since there's only a single instance of your BrowseFolder class, you're setting a property on the class and then attempting to reuse that in recursion. So basically what it's doing is drilling into the first folder, then since `$this->srcFolder` just equals subsequent children of that, it makes no attempts to go further. Replace every instance of `$this->srcFolder` with just `$srcFolder`. The recursive function will then drill down into the first, then when it reaches the end, work its way back up to the first call of `browse()`, then continue onto the second, and so on.

**Edit** - additional detail:
It *shouldn't* be modifying the variable each time. What it's doing is taking the first folder `images`, then setting that property on the class. It goes down into the first child of that folder - call it `folder1`, then again sets the class property to that child (i.e. `$this->srcFolder == "images/folder1"`). It lists the files in that folder, then continues on. Since there are no more files or subdirectories in that folder, it's reached the end of that iteration. So then it goes back up a level to the `images` folder. It goes to the next iteration of the `foreach` loop and now sets `$val` to `folder2`. Now it tries both `if(is_file($this->srcFolder.$val))` and `else if (is_dir($this->srcFolder.$val)`. The translation of that is `is_file("images/folder1/folder2")` since `$this->srcFolder` equals `images/folder1`. As a result, this always returns `false` until it just reaches the end of the `foreach` and exits.

If you instead call `$srcFolder` (local variable), then it will have the correct value each time it gets to the function. In the same scenario: it goes into `folder1` and just inside the second level of the `browse()` function, `$srcFolder == "images/folder1"`. It lists each element of that folder, then goes back up to `images`. Now the function still has its initial value for `$srcFolder`, which is `"images"`. So then in the second iteration of the `foreach` loop, now `$val` again equals `folder2`, so it calls `browse()` on that. Again in the second level of the function, `$srcFolder == "images/folder2"`. Using a local variable in recursion ensures that each call of the function will have the value it needs.

Comment: Thanks,@ChicagoRedSox. The first problem is saw it.Was only a check-up function. The second one...Well, i think my function is modyfing the $srcFolder class variable every time is changing the path. So, why isn't working?

Comment: I think the problem reside in this code: $this->srcFolder.$val  .I think srcFolder.$val tries to concatenate and then resolve $this. Something like that: ($this->)srcFolder.$val. Or? @ChicagoRedSox

Comment: See my long addition to the answer